# Task scheduler can't running after update in same day

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

i have one task scheduler with 2 action.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2020-07-21T08:40:20.4842672</Date>
    <Author>WIN-9DQ9EVI3R22\Administrator</Author>
    <URI>\RESTORE</URI>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2020-07-21T00:00:00</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-21-316211975-241055689-3246940587-500</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>LeastPrivilege</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>"D:\Batch File\LS_RESTORE_221.bat"</Command>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>"D:\Batch File\LS_RESTORE_MAINDB.bat"</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

my issue if i change or update action or trigger task scheduler not running in same day. but tommorrow in  same trigger task schduler running normal.

example at 21 Jul 2020 i change action file on task scheduler. but i see task scheduler can't running. i see 22 Jul 2020 task scheduler running normal.

so whats wrong on my task scheduler